# Hibernate Callbacks not triggering

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

As the subject says, my annotated Hibernate callback methods are not triggering when they should. Here is my configuration, perhaps someone could suggest what I'm missing. I am trying to follow the basic instructions [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html), though they seem to have a typo in their example code ("Audit.class"???) though we're not formally using JPA annotations (instead using the hbm.xml files), they should still be available with `hibernate-entitymanager` correct?

**Java object:**

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(Objectlistener.class)
public class Bannedword implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Date createddate;
    private Date lastmodifieddate;
         /**/
    public Date getCreateddate() {
        return createddate;
    }

    public void setCreateddate(Date createddate) {
        this.createddate = createddate;
    }

    public Date getLastmodifieddate() {
        return lastmodifieddate;
    }

    public void setLastmodifieddate(Date lastmodifieddate) {
        this.lastmodifieddate = lastmodifieddate;
    }
}
```

**Object listener:**

```
public class Objectlistener {
    /**
     * automatic property set before any database persistence
     */
    @PreUpdate
    public void setLastmodifieddate(Bannedword word) {
        System.out.println("Object listner!");
        word.setLastmodifieddate(new Date());
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void setCreateddate(Bannedword word){
        System.out.println("Object listner!");
        word.setCreateddate(new Date());
    }

}
```

**Bannedword.hbml.xml** (I realize createddate and lastmodifieddate) aren't mapped yet - but I don't think they need to be in order to get the triggers to fire?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Oct 14, 2013 5:24:09 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="objects.Bannedword" table="bannedword">
        <id name="id" type="string">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="uuid2" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="client" class="objects.Client" fetch="select">
            <column name="clientid" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="word" type="string">
            <column name="word" />
        </property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Hibernate related **POM.xml** entries:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.CR1</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.0.Final</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
       <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
```

And finally the **sessionfactory** stuff, I attempted to add the reflection manager stuff based on reading [here](http://leakfromjavaheap.blogspot.com/2013/08/prepersist-and-preupdate-not-working.html)

```
private SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() throws HibernateException{
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        ReflectionManager reflectionManager = configuration.getReflectionManager();

//      EntityCallbackHandler callbackHandler = new EntityCallbackHandler();
//      callbackHandler.add(Bannedword.class, null, null);
//      EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
//      
        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

Comment: Should this be @EntityListeners(class=Objectlistener.class) ?

Comment: I've seen it notated both ways, but Eclipse was adding a error marker- I can try to compile it again

Comment: confirmed - it throws a hibernate parsing exception

Comment: I think you can also use interceptors, these are easier to implement if your goal is to intercept/audit each save http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/events.html